# Torchvision model different behavior after torch.hub

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to fix some odd import behavior I'm seeing

This does not work:

```
import torchvision
dilated_model = torchvision.models.resnet50(
    pretrained=True, 
    replace_stride_with_dilation=[False, False, True]
)
```

> resnet50() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_stride_with_dilation'

But this does

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)

import torchvision
dilated_model = torchvision.models.resnet50(
    pretrained=True, 
    replace_stride_with_dilation=[False, False, True]
)
```

What's going on? In the torchvision github code, replace_stride_with_dilation should be valid... and my torch/torchvision packages are up to date (torch=1.8.1, torchvision=0.9.1)

---

Update: no clue what caused the issue, but it went away after `pip uninstall torchvision && pip install torchvision`.

Comment: Interesting. I do not get any error message in the first case, and I directly copy-pasted your code.

Comment: Thanks, seeing this prompted me to try an uninstall/reinstall (rather than just pip install -U ...). That fixed the issue. I'll keep this up as a note so that others waste less time